# query planner chooses non-optimal plans for view that is union of tables

Tags: postgresql, union, sql-execution-plan

I have a PostgreSQL database that is partitioned into multiple schemas, one for each tenant and workspace (the exact meaning of these terms doesn't matter, they're just dimensions of the partition scheme):

```
reports/tenant1/workspace1
reports/tenant1/workspace2
reports/tenant2/workspace1
reports/tenant3/workspace1
reports/tenant3/workspace2
reports/tenant3/workspace3
```

Each workspace schema has the same set of tables with identical definitions, and each table includes "_tenant" and "_workspace" columns with the values of its enclosing schema, e.g., tenant1 and workspace1.

In the public schema, there is one view per table definition that unions the tables with that definition across all workspace schemas. For example, the view for "example_table" would be:

```
SELECT _tenant, _workspace, column1, column2, column3
FROM "reports/tenant1/workspace1".example_table
WHERE _tenant = 'tenant1' AND _workspace = 'workspace1'
UNION ALL
SELECT _tenant, _workspace, column1, column2, column3
FROM "reports/tenant1/workspace2".example_table
WHERE _tenant = 'tenant1' AND _workspace = 'workspace2'
UNION ALL
SELECT _tenant, _workspace, column1, column2, column3
FROM "reports/tenant2/workspace1".example_table
WHERE _tenant = 'tenant2' AND _workspace = 'workspace1'
UNION ALL
```

*Note the "redundant" partition predicates in each SELECT. I added these because it seems to provide a hint to PostgreSQL not to execute queries on tables in unrelated partitions when querying the view with the same predicate. Indeed, EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows "(never executed)" for those queries.*

Queries are made from a BI tool to the views, and the BI tool automatically adds predicates on the "_tenant" and "_workspace" columns based on attributes of the logged-in user.

Now that there are 50+ workspaces, I've noticed that queries on the views can have non-optimal plans when compared to equivalent queries on the underlying tables. For example, the following query on the views might use a nested loop join that takes 1 minute:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT column1, column2, column3
  FROM example_view1
  WHERE _tenant = 'tenant1' AND _workspace = 'workspace1'
) v1
JOIN
(
  SELECT column4, column5, column6
  FROM example_view2
  WHERE _tenant = 'tenant1' AND _workspace = 'workspace1'
) v2
ON v1.column1 = v2.column4
```

Whereas the equivalent query on the underlying tables would use a hash join and complete in under a second:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT column1, column2, column3
  FROM "reports/tenant1/workspace1".example_table1
  WHERE _tenant = 'tenant1' AND _workspace = 'workspace1'
) v1
JOIN
(
  SELECT column4, column5, column6
  FROM "reports/tenant1/workspace1".example_table2
  WHERE _tenant = 'tenant1' AND _workspace = 'workspace1'
) v2
ON v1.column1 = v2.column4
```

*I know the subqueries are pointless, but it's how the BI tool's query builder generates the SQL for the join.*

Is there a way to let the query planner know that all tables outside the selected partition won't return results and can be ignored? As I said before, EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows queries are never executed on these tables due to the "redundant" partition predicates in the view definition, but that doesn't seem to be used at planning time.